# Java - farkle (greed) game (die and player arrays, multiple classes)

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, dice

I am trying to write code for a command like game of Farkle (greed). This is an Intro to computer science class. In a nutshell, you roll 6 die, and scores are based off of what you roll. Then you are required to remove the die that were used -> display score from that roll -> display total score -> ask if they would like to roll again. First player to a score determined by the user is the winner.

I have a bunch of code written for the model, and I am working on the view. I am struggling with the view, which makes it harder to advance on my model code. We are required to use the Die and Player classes (we were given those). I use the Die quickly, not quite sure how to apply the Player class.

When I try to run my command line, I am getting out of bounds errors on my rollCheck() array and other issues in my model that were not coming up when I simply was testing in main. I apologize for the amount of code posted, but I figure seeing everything makes it easier to solve (goes without saying really).

If anyone can give me pushes in the right direction to solving and making my program work, that would be great! Thank you.

Comment: On what line in the roll check method do you get the exception?

Comment: Also, you were correct not to post this code on paste bin, a question should be able to "live alone", as a general rule; short self contained code *is better than* long self contained code *is better than* non self contained code *is better than* no code

Comment: Updated post with the thrown exceptions.

Comment: GreedGame appears to be missing its "top"

Comment: Not really sure what that means, sorry.

Comment: As in your first code block just starts midway through, theres no `public class`, no declaration of variables, it just launches straight into a constructor. All your other code blocks (correctly) start `public class GreedCLI` or similar

Comment: the new first block of code is better but its still missing the `public class` bit. I know it sounds like i'm being picky but you've called super() within your constructor so i need to know what class you're extending, I can't just reverese engineer that bit

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to run the program to be sure its hard to be certain (I need the top of GreedGame) but i'd be fairly confident its the following:

in rollDie die is set to an array of ints on size remainingDie

```
this.die = new int [remainingDie];
```

later, within rollCheck the contents of the die array **up to and including** remainingDie, going over the array by 1

```
for (int i = 0; i <= remainingDie; i++) { // Count up quantity of die (6 set to remaining die)

     if (die[i] == 1) {
         this.numFreq[0] += 1;
     }
     ....
     ....
}
```

So in short I believe  `i <= remainingDie;` should be  `i < remainingDie;` because an array with 6 entries has "boxes" 0,1,2,3,4,5

Comment: I made the edit, and got a similar error, only the out of bounds exception is 5. The error seems to lie in rollCheck, it points me to the line of code in rollCheck: this.numFreq[i] = 0; The issue appears to be in the remainingDie itself, because if I replace it with simply 6, the command line runs a bit farther.

Comment: more comments! I passed availableDie(); to rollcheck and that seems to have helped. I will continue to mess with this, I appreciate the help. If you notice anything else, please throw it my way!